# How to get a text of certain elements BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this kind of html code

```
<tr>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">
    <p>
      <sup>
        Name Name Name
      </sup>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">
    <p>
      <sup>25.01.1980</sup>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

I need to get the text of every 3rd and 5th **td** of every **tr**

Apparently this doesn't work:)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import index

soup = BeautifulSoup(index.index_doc, 'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    print(i[2].text, i[4].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and pseudo classe [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to select your elements (assumed you need the date, so I selected the 6th td):

```
data = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('tr td:nth-of-type(3),tr td:nth-of-type(6)')]
```

And to get a list of `tuples`:

```
list(zip(data, data[1:]))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">
    <p>
      <sup>
        Name Name Name
      </sup>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">
    <p>
      <sup>25.01.1980</sup>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
  <td class="a">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('tr td:nth-of-type(3),tr td:nth-of-type(6)')]

list(zip(data, data[1:]))
```

Comment: One little thing, I asked for 3rd and 5th so it would be 'tr td:nth-of-type(3),tr td:nth-of-type(5)'
And soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
Thanks!

Comment: I assumed you need the date and that is the 6th in your example, but you are right, simply change the index. `lxml` is the `BeautifulSoup` standard parser, so there is no need to wirte it down, but you are free to do for readabillity. Cheers